# PayPal IPN always gets status - Queued

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, sandbox

I'm really struggling with PayPal IPN. I tested my IPN listener with IPN Simulator and everything seems fine. But when I use Sandbox every IPN gets status "Queued": http://prnt.sc/asjqvp

Do you have any idea why this might happen and how to fix that?

PS. It worked after a few hours. But it would be nice to know why it takes so much time...

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be a glitch on PayPal end... a simple search on Stack Overflow finds many people [with the same issue.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18814127/paypal-ipn-status-queued)

You can review the PayPal docs here - there's not really much details given, only "Queued - PayPal is ready to send the message."

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNOperations/