# PayPal IPN simulator works fine but IPN not responding to sandbox payments

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn

If I send an IPN from here https://developer.paypal.com/developer/ipnSimulator/ it works fine.

If I make a payment directly from my site using a PayPal sandbox account and a PayPal standard button, the IPN listener doesn't pick anything up. Here's the PayPal button on my site (note that it does link to PayPal's sandbox and the notify_url is specified correctly):

```
                <form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
                    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
                    <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
                    <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
                    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
                    <input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="services">

                    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="payments@www.com">
                    <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="21-2360-4" id="itemNumber">
                    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Listing Fee">
                    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="https://www.com/Market">
                    <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="https://www.com/Seller">
                    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="10" id="amount">

                    <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="https://www.com/IPN">
                    <p><button type="submit" id="sellButton">Pay fee and list</button></p>
                </form>
```

Here's my IPN listener code which works fine for IPNs made from the PayPal IPN simulator page but not for sandbox payments made using the form above (note it is also listening to PayPal's sandbox):

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST'){
    exit();
}

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://ipnpb.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "cmd=_notify-validate&" . http_build_query($_POST));
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

if($response == "VERIFIED"){
     // Successful purchase code.
}
```

Any clues as to why it doesn't pick up the IPN would be much appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, misread there.

Answer (score 1):

**Modified Info**
Log into the recipient Paypal account and setup IPN

Steps
Profile -> Profile and Settings -> My selling tools -> Instant payment notifications -> update

Click "Choose IPN settings"

Set the "Notification URL" field to what you have on "notify_url" in the HTML form.

Choose "Recieve IPN Messages"

Save

Note: If you check IPN history, it may come up as Queued. This seems to be a Sandbox glitch or maybe its handling many requests and has a long queue. You can try a live payment with a small value (e.g $1).
See here: [Paypal IPN Status - Queued](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18814127/paypal-ipn-status-queued)

*now irrelevant---
This should be a comment but I don't have the clearance to make comments.
You have `<button name="submit">Purchase with PayPal</button>`
That should be `<button type="submit">Purchase with PayPal</button>`
Please provide the full Paypal html code within the `<form></form>` tags.*

Comment: I've changed the button type and added the full code.

Comment: hope my modified answer helps

Comment: I've enabled IPN on the recipient account although that's not a long term solution as it won't always be the same email receiving payments. Also PayPal says specifying the notify_url will work. Second paragraph is useful although there's no notifications popping up at all - not even 'queued'.